# Retrieving data from Mac PCI SSD using windows PC?

Tags: mac, hard-drive, windows, ssd, data-transfer

My MacBook Pro Retina (model no A1502) recently died so I have taken out the SSD to try and retrieve its data using my windows pc.

I slotted the SSD into a PCI-e 4x adapter and installed it in onto my windows motherboard.

The PC does not recognise the drive on file explorer but does show up using the disk management (partitioning) tool:

[image: DiskManagementMacSSD]

I have tried installing HFSExplorer but it does not identify any compatible drives and I cannot locate the file path of the drive as it does not show up.

As shown on the image the disk seems to be in working order and it recognises the drive.

Any ideas on how to extract its data?