# Repairing Mac SSD from Windows when HFS/APFS viewers don't work

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, external-disk, repair

My friend's 2015 13" MacBook Pro had water spilled on it, and no longer works.  I want to extract the files contained for him.

I removed the SSD from the Mac, and connected it to my Windows 10 laptop using a [USB to M.2 PCIe M-Key slot adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VVNGYFV) + [Mac SSD to M.2 PCIe M-Key slot adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0173ODBCE).  The USB adapter now displays a solid blue light.

Trying to use both `MacDrive 10 Standard` (version `10.5.4.9`) and `HFSExplorer` (version `0.23.1`), I cannot see the SSD.  From `Disk Management` (version `10.0.18362.1`), I can sort of see the disk (it's unknown, but it shows up).  I do not want to initialize the disk, because (I think) that would wipe the drive.

From my work's MacBook Pro, I cannot see it at all using `Disk Utility` (version `18.0`).

I am wondering if the Mac's SSD is corrupted.  Does anyone have any tips to prove that it's corrupted?  I believe my hardware connections are good.

---

**What I See**

When I go into `Computer Management` --> `Disk Management`, here is what I see:

[image: Disk Management]

Using `DiskPart` (version `10.0.18362.1`), here are the drive details:

```
DISKPART> select disk 1

Disk 1 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

JMicron Generic SCSI Disk Device
Disk ID: 00000000
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.
```

---

It seems this unanswered question may be related: [Retrieving data from Mac PCI SSD using windows PC?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372922/retrieving-data-from-mac-pci-ssd-using-windows-pc)

Comment: MacDrive's web page says 10.5 beta is needed for APFS drives - https://www.macdrive.com Without APFS support, nothing will be able to handle it at all.

Comment: Assuming you need APFS not HFS, Paragon have published a read-only APFS driver for Linux/Windows on GitHub here: https://github.com/Paragon-Software-Group/paragon_apfs_sdk_ce